# Read File in Node and process the same

Tags: node.js, readline

I wanted to read a file and process each line of the file. I have used the readStream to read the file and then invoke the processRecord method. The processMethod need to make multiple calls and need to make the final data before its written to the store.

The file has 500K records.

The issue that Im facing is that, the files are read at a significant pace and I believe the node is not getting enough priority to actually process the processLine method. Hence the memory shoots upto 800MB and then slows down.

Any help is appreciated.

The code that Im using is given below -

```
var instream = fs.createReadStream('C:/data.txt');
var outstream = new stream;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: instream,
        output: outstream,
        terminal: false
});
outstream.readable = true;

rl.on('line', function(line) {

 processRecord(line);   
    }
```

Comment: As per the below comment, try the byline package and it has the same issue as readline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Node.js readline module is intended more for user interaction than line-by-line streaming from files. You may have better luck with the popular [byline](https://npmjs.org/package/byline) package.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var byline = require('byline');

// You'll need to check the encoding.
var lineStream = byline(fs.createReadStream('C:/data.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' }));

lineStream.on('data', function (line) {
    processRecord(line);
});
```

You'll have a better chance of avoiding memory leaks if the data is piped to another stream. I'm assuming here that `processRecord` is feeding into one. If you make it [a transform stream object](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform), then you can use pipes.

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

lineStream.pipe(processRecordStream).pipe(out);
```

Comment: The byline is also showing the same problem as with readline.

Comment: This is likely to be a problem with processRecord. What is it doing with the data? You may be retaining references and leaking memory. If you can, try to make it into a transform stream as I suggest in the second part of my answer.